# I can't detect click count = 2 (double click) in my java project

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I am trying to listen for double click on the jtable but the mouse listener only receive click count = 1.

```
JTable replacedAssets = new JTable(...);
replacedAssets.addMouseListener ( new MouseAdapter ( ) {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked ( MouseEvent e ) {
            super.mouseClicked ( e );
            if ( e.getClickCount () == 2 ) {
                rowIndex = replacedAssets.getSelectedRow ();
                columnIndex = replacedAssets.getSelectedColumn ();
                if ( rowIndex == 0 && ( columnIndex == 1 || columnIndex == 2 ) ) {
                    initial = replacedAssets.getValueAt ( rowIndex , columnIndex );
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( parent , "Editing this Field may cause error in the data causing problems." , "Error Edit Not Permitted For This Field" , JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

This is my mouse listener Code Please help.
PS: It works normally for JLabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `mouseClicked`  with `mousePressed` worked for me. I believe it is because `mouseClick` is a combination of `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`. If the mouse moves even a pixel between the two events an event will not be generated.

```
replacedAssets.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                super.mousePressed(mouseEvent);
                JTable table = (JTable) mouseEvent.getSource();
                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 ) {
                    System.out.println("Double click detected");
                }
           }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was that easy but I didn't realize that.